# I've upgraded my Concrete5 site to 5.6.0, and I'm getting `Fatal error, failed to open /concrete/models/json.php`

Tags: concrete5

After upgrading my site past 5.6.0, I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/concrete/models/json.php' in /concrete/core/libraries/loader.php on line 40
```

How can I fix this?

---

This issue ended up being the TweetCrete package, it has been updated since but is pretty far behind now. Consider updating to modern concrete5!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is [*Jereme's TweetCrete*](http://www.concrete5.org/marketplace/addons/tweetcrete/).
With the following files, override and remove `loader::model('json')`

- packages/jereme_tweetcrete/libraries/twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php Line 3
- packages/jereme_tweetcrete/models/tweetcrete_hash_tag.php Line 4

---

EDIT: This package was eventually updated and shouldn't need this modification anymore.